# Azure Active Directory B2C: Use conditional User Flow for Sign In based on Application Claim

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, multi-factor-authentication

When a user signs in, is it possible to let Azure Active Directory B2C pick the User Flow to use for Sign-In based on an Application Claim?

The behavior i am trying to create is, that the user enters his e-mail and ADB2C then routes to one of the available policies based on an application claim the user enters during sign-up.

This should allow us to have Multi-Factor-Authentication activated (or deactivated) on a User-Level. Currently you can only activate or deactivate [MFA on a User Flow-Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/multi-factor-authentication?pivots=b2c-user-flow), so my idea would be to have 2 User Flows, one with MFA activated and one without MFA and then use the respective User Flow based on a criteria of the user (e.g. Application Claim). It would be even better to have a Hook decide which User Flow to user but afaik this is not possible at the moment.

I know i can use [Custom Policies](https://www.kallemarjokorpi.fi/blog/azure-b2c-custom-mfa-implementation.html) to customize the login flow but this seems to be a quite painful experience so i try to stick with User flows as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple to do with one custom policy - just use a precondition in the user journey. My [tool](https://aka.ms/iefsetup) deploys custom policies for you to get started.

You could set an attribute on the user profile to conditionally run the MFA step, or via some other logic, like domain name detection.

Doing this with two user flows will create lots of problems.

Comment: @jas-suri-mft I downloaded the Custom Policy Starter Kit but i do not understand how to modify it to create the custom policy using the precondition and the custom claim. I do not even understand how to model the custom attributes i created in my user flows in the custom policy. The documentation is incomplete here. I did specify the extension Application in the AAD-Common TechnicalProfile but i don't know how to include the attributes in my Custom SignInSignUp-Policy to collect them during signup or to return them after signin. Also i'm lost how to model the user journey as you suggested.

Comment: @jas-suri-mfi Could you point me to any samples doing something similar to get me started? Or could you explain your suggested approach more in detail?

Comment: @jas-suri-msft Also could you please elaborate on the problems you might see arise from using two user flows? One problem i see is that an unauthenticated call to a backend api is required to check if the user has MFA activated in order to redirect him to the correct login flow. Do you see any other issues?

Comment: Another problem might be is that we have to prevent Sign-In-Operations using the "wrong" user flow (e.g. when a user has MFA activated but tries to sign in using the Non-MFA-Flow). Could be achieved using an API Connector returning an error response if coming from the wrong user flow.